# Parsing HTML with PHP code

Tags: php, html, xml, simplexml

I have some files that come in that also have php server code in them.  The are expected.  I'm wondering if there are is a way with SimpleXMLDom to parse the elements even though there are php tags in the document.

Example

```
<html>
    <? if(false) { ?>
    Never print this
    <? } ?>
</html>
```

I'd like to get the contents of html in plain text with the php server tags.  It seems like just loading this block of code will cause exceptions.

I know it's really easy to eval the entire block by the following:

```
eval('?>'.$html.'<?');
```

but what I'd like to be able to do is pull an element and if there is php evaluate the code, much like was given below, but it doesn't seem I can load html code with php and parse it via SimpleXMLDom if there is a trick with the library or another that will do this simply

Comment: How sophisticated is this code? One possible approach is to `eval` that block with output buffer enabled (with `include`, for example), then parse the collected contents of that buffer. Apparently, it is not a good idea if there's even a slightest possibility that PHP code might turn rogue.

Comment: yes, but I'd like to only eval the php code once I traverse the dom tree not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
<?php 
   $xml=simplexml_load_file("your_file.php");


   foreach($xml->children() as $child)
   {
     if (substr(ltrim($child->getName(), " \t"), 0,1) == "?">{
        you have php code
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: that would be great if that was possible but just loading the file causes an error.

Comment: This mean the php is not an xml well formatted.. if is so you can't use simplexml for parsing but you can think about a text parsing..

Comment: I did ask if it's not possible with SimpleXmlDom, how can it be done?

Comment: You can do with a simple file loading as text and perform a loop similar to the loop in answer for each row/line .. in this way you can find the line containing  <?= or <?php . I don't know if this is what you need but it is quite easy .if this is what you need i can update the answer this way..